# declare variable which will be an object php

Tags: php, var, declare

I want to declare all the variables that i will use in a script on top of it,eg

```
$user_class= '';
$user_id = 0;
$user_profile = '';
```

What should be used for $user_class which will be an object?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a user class, you can declare it as a standard object:

```
$user = new stdClass();
$user->class = "employee";
$user->id = 0;
```

To declare a class *User*:

```
class User
{
    // property declaration
    public $id;
    public $class;
}

// usage
$u1 = new User();
```

Comment: Yes i believe that would be the only way,i am curious though maybe other people do it different.

Comment: I've added an example of creating a class

Comment: It's actually gonna be an instance of Facebook SDK class.